# Reference files from bower_components

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bower

My `index.html` file is not loading the Angular files in the `bower_components` folder or my `app.js` folder when I run `http-server`. This is for a simple tutorial I am doing. So I know the structure is not ideal

Angular-Weather

```
-- app   
   --home.html
   --index.html
   --own-app.js
-- bower_components
   --angular
     --angular.js
   --angular-route
     --angular-route.js
-- bower.json
-- README.md
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
 <html lang="en" ng-app="OWMApp">
   <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Open Weather Map App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div ng-view></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="owm-app.js"></script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in browser console?

Comment: What's your server? Is it Node? Possibly with express?

Comment: Just a GET failed (status 404) for the above scripts

Answer (score 4):

It is because the `bower_components` folder is not inside the `app` folder, so the *http-server* cannot serve it because it does not exist.

I guess the folder was created automatically for you by bower. You can tell bower to create it inside the `app` folder, for that create a `.bowerrc` file in the root directory with:

```
{
    "directory": "app/bower_components"
}
```

The next `bower install` will install it the correct place.

Comment: Sorry I did not edit it the original doc correctly, the root folder is Angular-Weather which holds the sub folders app and  bower_components. So i ran the `bower init` command within the the Angular-Weather directory. You are saying I should still do the above based on this?

Comment: Absolutely. You can quickly check out if my suggestion helps, if you manually copy the `bower_components` folder into the `app` folder. If this works, then my solution should help.